Trying to integrate TinyMCE into django but TinyMCE editor is not showing up
I'm following along sentdex's django development tutorial.
This is the code in the admin.py file
class TutorialAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    fieldsets = [
        ("Title/date", {"fields": ["tutorial_title", "tutorial_published"]}),
        ("Content", {"fields": ["tutorial_content"]})    
        ]
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.TextField: {'widget': TinyMCE()}

        }

admin.site.register(Tutorial, TutorialAdmin)

the tinyMCE editor is not showing up in the site
I tried to add TinyMCE to a django site, but it is not showing up. How do I get TinyMCE to show up?

Check the comments of the YouTube video. It's not obvious, I had to dig. Looks like you need to use pip install django-tinymce instead, then configure it by defining TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG. Untested. Just what I was able to glean.
